# AngularJs ng-repeat array inside array order child

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using angularJS to view my data. My data is an array inside an array. I need to show the `Tickets` without the order of the object above(User). I like to select to order later. For these example we use Date
as order indicator.

Model

```
Array[2]
  0: Object
    UserId: 1
    Username: "firstUser"
    Tickets: Array[2]
      0: Object
        TicketId: "3"
        Date: "2014-05-11"
        Score: 100
      1: Object
        TicketId: "4"
        Date: "2014-02-11"
        Score: 100
  1: Object
     UserId: 1
     Username: "secondUser"
     Tickets: Array[1]
       0: Object
         TicketId: "1"
         Date: "2014-04-11"
         Score: 200
```

View

```
[Username: firstUser   TicketId:   3]
[Username: secondUser  TicketId:   1]
[Username: firstUser   TicketId:   4]
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to achieve please try to be more descriptive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be easier if you create a new array out of the existing data structure and then order the transformed array by date. Here is a [<kbd>**plunker**</kbd>](http://plnkr.co/edit/Wl0w6ZD1LpMTIX9PzWdY?p=preview) demonstrating the same.

Mainly,

```
$scope.transform = function() {
    var transformedArray = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.samples, function(item){
      angular.forEach(item.Tickets, function(ticket){
        transformedArray.push({
          userName: item.Username, 
          ticketId: ticket.TicketId, 
          date: ticket.Date
        });
      });
    });

    return transformedArray;
}
```